# PHP not working on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-10.10

I just recently installed an Ubuntu Server 10.10 but php doesn't seem to work. I created a file to show phpinfo() to make sure php works but it doesn't show anything. I looked for php.ini and I found three files:

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/ets/php5/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini

**EDIT:** Ooops! That was embarassing. I copied files from a different server and for some reason the permissions changed, this includes the test file that I use to test php. All I have to do is change the permission on all the files. SORRY about that this is a very stupid/nooby error on my part.

Comment: how are are you trying to run PHP? Apache module, fastcgi, cgi? Can you run PHP at the command line? Which web server are you using? etc etc. much more info is needed to try to diagnose this.

Comment: Can you paste the php file are you using for test?

Answer (score 0):

Is `libapache2-mod-php5` installed?  Is the module enabled?  `ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled`

Comment: did the ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and here's the result:   > ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
  alias.conf
  alias.load
  auth_basic.load
  authn_file.load
  authz_default.load
  authz_groupfile.load
  authz_host.load
  authz_user.load
  autoindex.conf
  autoindex.load
  cgi.load
deflate.conf
deflate.load
dir.conf
dir.load
env.load
mime.conf
mime.load
negotiation.conf
negotiation.load
php5.conf
php5.load
reqtimeout.conf
reqtimeout.load
setenvif.conf
setenvif.load
status.conf
status.load

Comment: try this:  <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>, you may just be doing <? phpinfo() ?> and in some cases that doesn't show the info.

Comment: Sean, That what exactly what my test file looks like, but it turns out that the permission on the file was not set, that's why it's not displaying anything (see edited post). That was my stupid mistake. Thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted apache?

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the module enabled ?
You need libapache2-mod-php5 and php5-common
After that enable the module
If apache2, apachectl -M gives you the loaded modules